# Issue in Mocking Fetch API with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to mock fetch API with Jest but facing issue that assertions run before the fetch is resolved so tests always fail. Here is the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-2evvr

I also tried async/await but still same issue :

```
it("should update result on successful fetch", async () => {
    const updateSearchResult = jest.fn();
    await handleSearch("api");
    expect(updateSearchResult).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

How can fix this , so that code runs after finally block of fetch . thanks

Comment: You can use the `done` argument in Jest for your fetch tests. Jest will not finish the test unless `done()` is called, so you can have your `expect` for your fetch before calling `done()`. [More information here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)

Comment: thanks for reply , but here handlesearch does not takes a callback , could u pls let me know how I can refactor tests here : https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-2evvr

Comment: `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` expects a function, but in your codesandbox sample, `result` is not a function. What you would want to do is simply adding the `done` argument, then run `handleSearch("api")` followed by your `expect`, and end it with `done()`. Something like your "should reset Search result on fetch failure" section, but just adding `done` to the arrow function and `done()` after your `expect` line.

Comment: @Alfred async..await is already in use. It shouldn't be used with `done` as they serve the same purpose and `async` is more high-level.

Comment: @Bhupendra Please, provide all relevant code in the question itself, it should be understandable without navigating to external links that may become unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleSearch` doesn't return a promise which is an antipattern, so `await handleSearch("api")` doesn't affect anything. It will also fail if no `callback` is provided. Native promises allow to provide a non-function to `then`, in this case it's ignored. Since a callback should receive same parameters as `then` callback, it should be:

```
function handleSearch(searchQuery, callback) {
  return fetch(searchQuery)
  .then(callback)
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked ,returning promising from handleSearch  and then testing like ```handleSearch("api").then(() => {
      expect(updateSearchResult).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });```

Comment: It's safer to use async..await in tests. Not returning `handleSearch("api")` promise from a test will make it synchronous, it will always pass.

Answer (score 0):

well this is my approach to mock a `async` function :

```
    let resolve , reject;
    jest.mock("../module,()=>({
    ...jest.requireActual("../module"),
    handleSearch:jest.fn(()=> new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    resolve = res;
    reject = rej
    }))
    }))

it("should update result on successful fetch", async () => {
    const updateSearchResult = jest.fn();
    await handleSearch();
    resolve("api")
    expect(handleSearch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Comment: It seems to be handleSearch test so it doesn't make much sense to mock tested unit. `handleSearch` is surely expected to be called because it was explicitly called 2 lines above.

Comment: i am showcasing the mock approach so if you are looking to mock a aync function inside a function you can use it.